# Get cookie from InternetExplorer object

Tags: vba, cookies

I'm working a VBA project uses the following code to automate IE. How can I able to get cookies from current IE session?

Sub IE()

```
Dim objIE  As InternetExplorer
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate "targeturl"
While objIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

getCookie = objIE.Cookie
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
getCookie = objIE.document.Cookie
```

Comment: Get empty content, Windows 8 and IE11

Comment: Then maybe there's no cookie, or it's an "HTTP only" cookie.

Comment: Yes il's HTTP only. Is it possible to get cookie from header?

Comment: Sorry - never had to deal with that problem.